# Problems of bootstrap navigation's menu and logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1: I want to change size of logo and  name in bootstrap navigation.

2: I have navigation menu, but it not appearing.

[image]

**Navbar:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-4  fig-nav">
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
  <!-- Logo Image -->
  <img src="./assets/logo.svg" width="50" height="50" alt="" class="d-inline-block 
  align-middle mr-3 img-responsive">
  <!-- Logo Text -->
  <span style="color:#ffffff" class="text-size text-decoration-none font-weight- 
bold">Name</span>
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
 expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"><a href="about.vue" class="nav-link nav-link:hover ">About 
  </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item "><a href="products.vue" class="nav-link nav- 
    link:hover">Products</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item "><a href="information.vue" class="nav-link nav- 
    link:hover">Information</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item "><a href="jobs.vue" class="nav-link nav-link:hover">Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You made some mistakes in your code. Please check my code.
2. I am assuming you are using Bootstrap-5 where negative margins are disabled by default but can be enabled in Sass by setting $enable-negative-margins: true. Read their documentation - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#negative-margin.
   OR
   use Bootstrap-4
   OR
   use your custom CSS.

Please check my code.

```css
 .navbar-nav{
        margin-left: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-expand-lg py-4  fig-nav">
        <div class="container">
        
            <!-- Logo Image -->
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" class="d-inline-block 
            align-middle mr-3 img-responsive">
            <!-- Logo Text -->
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Name</a>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
            target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
            expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="about.vue" class="nav-link nav-link:hover ">About </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="products.vue" class="nav-link nav- 
                link:hover">Products</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="information.vue" class="nav-link nav- 
                link:hover">Information</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="jobs.vue" class="nav-link nav-link:hover">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        
          </div>
          </nav>
</body>
</html>
```